# mySQL show logs within a time range from each message?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do this in one query? For example, I have a table called logs with the following columns: id, epoch, username, msg.

I need to search for messages from a certain user, like so:

```
select * from logs where username = 'bob'
```

And now I want to select all messages from bob within a certain time range from that message.

I know I can do this easily in PHP using a for loop, but I have to use mySQL.

I originally thought of doing something like this:

```
select * from logs where FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch) between
(select FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch) from logs where username = 'bob')
and
ADDTIME((select FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch) from logs where username = 'bob'), '03:00:00')
```

But this won't work because my sub queries will return multiple values.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I would want to do this with multiple messages, for example, some psuedocode:

```
foreach epoch, message in (messages from logs where username = bob) as a do
print (select epoch, username, message from logs where epoch between a.epoch and ADDTIME(a.epoch, 3 hours))
end
```

But I have to use mySQL.  Is it possible to do this in mySQL?

Comment: _within a certain time range from that message_ ? But `select * from logs where username = 'bob'` would return multiple rows. What message is your starting point for the time range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than any sort of subquery, it sounds like what you want can be accomplished with a `LEFT JOIN` of the table against itself, but instead of a simple join condition, use the `epoch BETWEEN`... condition in the join's `ON` clause.

The left side of the join will be filtered to `username = 'bob'` while the right side will locate messages in the related data ranges.

Add a `DISTINCT` to deduplicate rows if needed.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  rng.epoch,
  rng.username,
  rng.message
FROM
  logs AS main
  LEFT JOIN logs as rng 
    /* Join the epoch values from the table to related rows within 3 hours */
    ON rng.epoch BETWEEN main.epoch AND (a.epoch + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
/* filter the main one for the desired username */
WHERE main.username = 'bob'
```

What isn't clear from your question yet is whether you ultimately only want `bob`'s rows returned. If that is the case, both sides of the join need to be filtered in the `WHERE` clause, or usernames matched in the `ON` clause:

```
FROM
  logs AS main
  LEFT JOIN logs as rng 
    ON rng.epoch BETWEEN main.epoch AND (a.epoch + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    /* match usernames so the related rows are only bob's
    AND main.username = rng.username
```